# Pass context from useQuery to Apollo client

Tags: reactjs, graphql, next.js, apollo, apollo-link

I'm building an next.js app in which I intend to consume several graphql-apis. I would like to pass a context when using the `useQuery` from `@apollo/react-hooks` in my components. At the moment my client looks like this:

```
import { ApolloClient } from '@apollo/client'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { ApolloLink } from 'apollo-link'

let apolloClient

function createApolloClient() {
    return new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
        link: new ApolloLink((operation) => {
            console.log(operation.getContext())
            return new HttpLink({
                uri: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql', // Server URL (must be absolute)
                credentials: 'same-origin', // Additional fetch() options like `credentials` or `headers`
            }).request(operation)
        }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    })
}

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
    const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()

    // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial state
    // get hydrated here
    if (initialState) {
        _apolloClient.cache.restore(initialState)
    }
    // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient
    // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
    if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient

    return _apolloClient
}

export function useApollo(initialState) {
    const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState])
    return store
}
```

and my Sample component looks like this:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import { initializeApollo } from '../lib/apolloClient'

interface Props {}

export const STRAPI = gql`
    query {
        questions {
            question
        }
    }
`

const Sample = (props: Props) => {
    const {
        loading: strapiLoading,
        error: strapiError,
        data: strapiData,
    } = useQuery(STRAPI, {
        context: {
            api: 'strapi',
        },
        notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{strapiData.questions[0].question}</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const apolloClient = initializeApollo()

    await apolloClient.query({
        query: STRAPI,
    })

    return {
        props: {
            initialApolloState: apolloClient.cache.extract(),
        },
        unstable_revalidate: 1,
    }
}

export default Sample
```

In the client I try to print the context with `console.log(operation.getContext())` and I expected to see `'context: 'api'` somewhere...but nothing. Could someone help me?

Comment: https://www.loudnoises.us/next-js-two-apollo-clients-two-graphql-data-sources-the-easy-way/

Comment: It works for me with above code. I hope that your components are wrapped by `<ApolloProvider />` in `_app.[js|tsx]`